# Error encountered during deployment in Production

Tags: apex

I am working on a requirement where I need to trigger email with all attachments on a ticket when owner gets changed. The below mentioned code works as expected in Sandbox and I get 87% code coverage but when we try to deploy in production the code coverage is reduced to 25% which I am unable to figure out what is causing it.
And We are getting error is

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, zGLOBAL_New_Owner_Notifi_Trigger: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.QueryException: Non-selective query against large object type (more than 200000 rows). Consider an indexed filter or contact salesforce.com about custom indexing. Even if a field is indexed a filter might still not be selective when: 1. The filter value includes null (for instance binding with a list that contains null) 2. Data skew exists whereby the number of matching rows is very large (for instance, filtering for a particular foreign key value that occurs many times)
>
> Class.zGLOBAL_New_Owner_Notifi_Attachment.emailSender: line 9, column 1
> Trigger.z

```
public class zGLOBAL_New_Owner_Notifi_Attachment  {

public static void emailSender(Map<Id,Case> oldMap, Map<Id,Case> newMap) {
    // this is a list for storing email for settoAddress 
    List<String>toAddress =new List<String>();
    // this is a list for storing email for setccAddress 
    List<String>CCAddress =new List<String>();
    
    List<contact> lstcont=[select id ,Email,name,phone from contact];
    Map<String,String> mapContact=new Map<String,String>();
    list<String> ccAddresslst=new List<String>();
    map<string,String> mapuser=new map<string,string>();    
    Set<Id> accIds=new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> recId=new Set<Id>();
   
    String ownerName=''; 
    String baseUrl = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
    
    //for getting user email and store in map where user id is key and email is value
    for(User u:[select id, name, Email from user]) 
    {
        mapuser.put(u.id,u.email);
    }
    
    //for getting Contact name  and store in map where  id is key and name is value
    for(contact con:lstcont)
    {
        mapContact.put(con.id,con.name);
    }
    
    
    //Change Trigger.new with udtCases
    for(Id key : oldMap.keySet())
    {
        case oldcase=oldMap.get(key);
       case cs=newMap.get(key);
        
        if(cs.zGloblal_Total_attachments__c>=1 && cs.APEX_Owner_notifications_Attachments__c==true)
        {
            //Changed Trigger.oldMap
          
            

            if(oldcase.OwnerId!=cs.OwnerId)
            {
               if(string.valueOf(cs.OwnerId).startsWith('005'))
                {
                    toAddress.add(mapuser.get(cs.OwnerId));  
                    ownerName=Getqueuemember.getOwnername(cs.OwnerId);
                }
                
                else{ 
                    CCAddress=Getqueuemember.getEmailfromuser(cs.OwnerId);
                    ownerName=Getqueuemember.getqueueOwnername(cs.OwnerId);
                }
                
                
                List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> fileAttachments = new List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>();
                List<Attachment> attlist=[select Name, Body, BodyLength from Attachment where ParentId = :cs.id ];
                for (Attachment a :attlist){
                    
                    Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
                    
                    efa.setFileName(a.Name);
                    efa.setBody(a.Body);
                    fileAttachments.add(efa);
                }
                
                
                String Subject='Ticket #'+cs.CaseNumber+' has been assigned to  '+' '+ownerName;
                
                
                
                try{
                    
                   
                    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage semail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                    
                    
                    
                    semail.setSubject(Subject); 
                    semail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Support'); 
                    semail.setTargetObjectId(cs.ContactId);
                    //semail.setTemplateId(et.id);
                    semail.setCcAddresses(CCAddress);
                    semail.setToAddresses(toAddress); 
                    
                    semail.setHtmlBody('***THIS IS A SYSTEM GENERATED MESSAGE! DO NOT REPLY!***<br/><br/>Please be advised that the following SalesForce ticket has been assigned to  '+ownerName+'<br/><br/> Ticket #:'+cs.CaseNumber+
                                       '<br/>Subject:'+cs.subject+'<br/><br/>Contact Name: '+mapContact.get(cs.Contactid)+'<br/>Contact Phone (primary): '+Getqueuemember.r(cs.ContactPhone)+'<br/>Contact Mobile (primary): '+Getqueuemember.r(cs.ContactMobile)+
                                       '<br/> Contact Email:'+Getqueuemember.r(cs.ContactEmail)+'<br/><br/>Category: '+Getqueuemember.r(cs.Ticket_Category__c)+Getqueuemember.r(cs.Service_Category__c)+Getqueuemember.r(cs.Ticket_Category2__c)+               
                                       '<br/>Type: '+Getqueuemember.r(cs.Ticket_Type__c)+Getqueuemember.r(cs.Service_Type__c)+Getqueuemember.r(cs.Ticket_Type2__c)+                           
                                       '<br/>Item: '+Getqueuemember.r(cs.Ticket_Item__c)+Getqueuemember.r(cs.Service_Item__c)+Getqueuemember.r(cs.Ticket_Item2__c)+                   
                                       '<br/>Ticket Source: '+Getqueuemember.r(cs.Case_Source__c)+'<br/><br/><br/>Building: '+Getqueuemember.r(cs.building__c)+'<br/>Room: '+Getqueuemember.r(cs.Room_Number__c)+'<br/>Area Description: '+Getqueuemember.r(cs.Area_description__c)+
                                       '<br/><br/><br/>Click the appropriate link below to view the ticket directly:<br/><br/>Partner Portal Users: <a href='+baseUrl+'/'+cs.id+'>'+baseUrl+'/'+cs.id+'</a><br/>BlackbeltHelp (Community Users): <a href='+Getqueuemember.getcommunityurl(cs.AccountId)+cs.id+
                                       '>'+Getqueuemember.getcommunityurl(cs.AccountId)+cs.id+'</a><br/><br/>Description:'+cs.Description+'<br/><br/>Internal Notes: '+Getqueuemember.r(cs.Internal_Notes__c)); 
                    semail.setFileAttachments(fileAttachments);     
                    semail.setWhatId(cs.id);
                 Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {semail}); 
                    
                }
                catch(exception e)    
                {}
                
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

and Test class is

```
@isTest
public class zGLOBAL_New_Owner_Notifi_AttachmentTest {
    @isTest
    public Static void emailTest()
    {
       // create test account
        Account acc = TestUtilityController.getAccount('MassBay');
        acc.APEX_Owner_notifications_Attachments__c=true;
        insert acc;
        
        // create test contact
        Contact con = TestUtilityController.getContact('Test Last Name','testing@testing.com',acc.Id);
        insert con;
        
        // fill utility
        UtilityController.fillUtilities();
        UtilityController.isUtility = false;
        
        trigger_control__c tc = new trigger_control__c();
        tc.name='test';
        tc.Enable_Owner_Notification_Trigger__c=true;
        insert tc;
        
        // Create test cases 
        List<Case> listCase = new List<Case>();
        
        if(UtilityController.caseRecordType.containsKey('MassBayCC_Ticket')){
            String recordTypeId = UtilityController.caseRecordType.get('MassBayCC_Ticket').Id;   
                 
             
            Case csanew = TestUtilityController.getCase(recordTypeId,con.Id,acc.Id);
            csanew.status = 'Action - Automated Escalation';
            csanew.zGloblal_Total_attachments__c=2;
            csanew.Ticket_Category2__c = 'Blackboard Learn - LMS';
            csanew.Ticket_Type2__c = 'Faculty/Staff';
            csanew.Ticket_Item2__c='Tutorial';
            listCase.add(csanew);
            
    //Added additional code here
     System.test.startTest();

            insert listCase;


System.Test.stopTest();

            Getqueuemember.getcommunityurl(acc.id);
            Getqueuemember.getEmailfromuser('0050W0000061RWD');
            Getqueuemember.getOwnername('0050W0000061RWD');
            Getqueuemember.getqueueOwnername('00Gd00000027kH7');
            Getqueuemember.r(csanew.Ticket_Category2__c);
        
    }

}
    
   

}
```

Comment: You should never hard-code Salesforce Ids in your unit test code. You should always insert, or query in the case of setup objects, for the records you need. That _may_ be the source of part of your issue.

Comment: You should also be writing high-quality test cases that do data setup, exercise of functionality, and assertion of results on _every_ code path. Calling a bunch of methods in a test to get "free" code coverage is valueless.

Answer (score 1):

You have an unfiltered query which pulls every `Contact` in the system, despite knowing which records you care about.

```
List<contact> lstcont=[select id ,Email,name,phone from contact];
```

Since you are just pulling this from a given `Case.ContactId` on your `newMap`, you can simply filter those values.

```
Set<Id> contactIds = new Set<Id>();
for (Case record : newMap.values())
    contactIds.add(record.ContactId);
Map<Id, Contact> contacts = new Map<Id, Contact>([
    SELECT Name, Email, Phone FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :contactIds
]);
```

Please note that you can instantiate a `Map<Id, SObject>` by passing in a `List<SObject>` and it consumes less CPU time, in addition to getting rid of boilerplate in your code.

Answer (score 0):

your test environment must not have as many records as production, you will need to refactor your query on an indexed field. If none of your fields are indexed, you can open a ticket with salesforce and ask them to index a particular field.